# Why npm package installs node_modules folder into itself?

Tags: npm, package.json

Why npm package installs node_modules folder into itself?
[npm folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ndP.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "description": "package",
  "main": "src/public-api.ts",
  "files": [
    "src/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "preversion": "npm run lint",
  "prepublishOnly": "npm run lint",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
  "prepare": "npm run build",
  
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0"
  }
}
```

If you remove node_modules in the package itself, then everything works fine.

Comment: It happened to me too, once, and I'm interested by the response. So I upvoted your question to cancel the unexplained downvote you received.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Are you asking why packages/dependencies installed through package.json have there own node_modules ? If so this is one of the architecture design, https://youtu.be/M3BM9TB-8yA?t=657  watch this talk to get a better understanding